# Use Webpack plugin output in entry. AngularTemplateCacheWebpackPlugin

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm using the AngularTemplateCacheWebpackPlugin to generate AngularJS component templates into javascript files.

My issue is, that I'm unable to include the output of the plugin into my webpack entry.
I've tried both adding is as an entry directly, but also imported it, into my main entry.
My plugins generate output files containing modules used in webpack.
Webpack is running prior to my plugins, so it is complaining about not finding the modules needed, as they are not yet generated and therefore doesn't exist.
I can't find any way that I can get plugins to run, before webpack validates the entry.

----UPDATE: Added webpack config code----

```
entry: {
    app: './src/index.ts'//,
    //templates: ['./dist/html-templates.js', './dist/modules-templates.js', './dist/scripts-templates.js'] does not work
},
output: {
    filename: "bundle-[contenthash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
},

new AngularTemplateCacheWebpackPlugin({
        source: 'Modules/**/*.html',
        outputFilename: 'modules-templates.js',
        module: 'modules-templates',
        standalone: true
    }),
```

Comment: Please add some code to add context

Comment: @Todd good idea, I just added some of snippets, from my webpack config.